# 3d Ring in Matlab using Patch

Tags: matlab

I am trying to make a 3d ring in a matlab. Following is something similar to what I am upto:

```
t = linspace(0,2*pi);
rin = 0.1;
rout = 0.25;
xin = 0.5 + rin*cos(t);% 0.5 is the center of the ring
xout = 0.5 + rout*cos(t);
yin = 0.5 + rin*sin(t);
yout = 0.5 + rout*sin(t);

% Make patch
hp = patch([xout,xin],[yout,yin],'g','linestyle','none','facealpha',0.25);
```

Now, I want to extend this to the 3d case. I wanted to give height to this ring. But when I try to add a vector `[z1,z2]` where

```
z1=0.5*ones(size(xin));
z2=z1;
```

I have tried different combination of Z1 and Z2 still I am unable to find the solution.

Comment: Cylinder,hollow from the center.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Duplicating your annulus and adding two cylinders i get:

```
%% Config
t = linspace(0,2*pi);
rin = 0.1;
rout = 0.25;
center = [1, 0.5];
xin = rin*cos(t);
xout = rout*cos(t);
yin = rin*sin(t);
yout = rout*sin(t);
z1 = 0;
z2 = 0.24;

%% Plot
clf;
hold on;
bottom = patch(center(1)+[xout,xin], ...
               center(2)+[yout,yin], ...
               z1*ones(1,2*length(xout)),'');
top = patch(center(1)+[xout,xin], ...
            center(2)+[yout,yin], ...
            z2*ones(1,2*length(xout)),'');
[X,Y,Z] = cylinder(1,length(xin));
outer = surf(rout*X+center(1), ...
             rout*Y+center(2), ...
             Z*(z2-z1)+z1);
inner = surf(rin*X+center(1), ...
             rin*Y+center(2), ...
             Z*(z2-z1)+z1);

set([bottom, top, outer, inner], ...
    'FaceColor', [0 1 0], ...
    'FaceAlpha', 0.99, ...
    'linestyle', 'none', ...
    'SpecularStrength', 0.7);
light('Position',[1 3 2]);
light('Position',[-3 -1 3]);
axis vis3d; axis equal; view(3);
```

[image: Cylinder]

Answer (score 5):

I tend to keep the usage of `patch` for 2D surfaces of object which are really faceted and if you need control over the properties of every face, otherwise for volumes like you want `surf` is a much easier object to handle.

The example below shows how to do it with one single `surface`, but is easily adaptable if you really need to use `patch`.

To explain step by step I start with the patch you created. I calculate the coordinates of the center line (called `ring` in the code), then display it (with the starting point highlighted)

```
%% // Ring properties
ring.x0 = 0.5 ;                 %// Center of ring
ring.y0 = 0.5 ;                 %// Center of ring
ring.radius = (0.25+0.1)/2   ;  %// Radius of core circle profile
ring.nDiv   = 37  ;             %// number of divisions for the core circle profile
ring.theta  = linspace(0,2*pi,ring.nDiv) ;
ring.X = cos(ring.theta) * ring.radius + ring.x0 ;
ring.Y = sin(ring.theta) * ring.radius + ring.y0 ;

%// plot (optional, just for intermediate visualisation)
hold on ; plot(ring.X,ring.Y) ; plot(ring.X(1),ring.Y(1),'ok')
view(18,72) ; xlabel('X') ; ylabel('Y') ; zlabel('Z') ;
```

which render:
[image: your patch]

Then I create a basic cross section:

```
%% // Create a base SQUARE cross section
Npts = 4 ;
cs.width  = 0.25-0.1 ;                        %// width of each cross section square
cs.height = 0.25     ;                        %// height of each cross section square

%// first cross section is the the XZ plane
csY0 = zeros(1,Npts) ;                        %// will be used as base for rotating cross sections
csX = [-cs.width/2 cs.width/2 cs.width/2 -cs.width/2 ]  ;
csZ = [-cs.height/2 -cs.height/2 cs.height/2 cs.height/2] ;
```

This defined a basic square hanging in space around the origin, I'll place the first one in position just to illustrate:

```
%% // plot (optional, just for intermediate visualisation)
hp0 = patch(csX+ring.X(1),csY0+ring.Y(1),csZ,'r','FaceAlpha',0.5) ;
view(164,38)
```

Which renders:
[image: the first cross section]

Now we just need to replicate this cross section wrapped around the master `ring`:

```
%% Generate coordinates for each cross section and merge them
nCS = length(ring.X) ; %// number of cross sections composing the surface

%// pre-allocation is always good
X = zeros( nCS , Npts ) ;
Y = zeros( nCS , Npts ) ;
Z = zeros( nCS , Npts ) ;

for ip = 1:nCS
   %// rotate the cross section (around Z axis, around origin)
   Rmat = [ cos(ring.theta(ip))  -sin(ring.theta(ip))    ; ...
            sin(ring.theta(ip))   cos(ring.theta(ip))   ] ;
   csTemp = Rmat * [csX ; csY0]  ;

   %// translate the coordinates of cross section to final position and store with others 
   X(ip,:) = csTemp(1,:) + ring.X(ip) ;
   Y(ip,:) = csTemp(2,:) + ring.Y(ip) ;
   Z(ip,:) = csZ  ;
end
```

Now you have in `X`,`Y` and `Z` the coordinates of points all around the profile you defined, ready to be plotted in one graphical object:

```
%% // Plot the final surface
hs = surf(X,Y,Z) ;
set(hs,'FaceColor',[.7 .7 .7],'FaceAlpha',0.5,'EdgeAlpha',0.2)
view(155,26)
```

Which renders:
[image: the full surface]

---

The 2 nice points about this method are:

- Only one graphic object to handle (still versatile though, the CData allows many possibilities)
- The cross section can be ***anything***, just define it once, and repeat the method.

To illustrate point 2 above, just replace the paragraph of code `%% // Create a base square cross section` by this circular cross section:

```
%% // Create a base CIRCULAR cross section
cs.Ndiv = 13 ; % 
cs.radius = (0.25-0.1)/2   ; %// Radius of each cross section circle
cs.rout = 0.25;
cs.theta = linspace(0,2*pi,cs.Ndiv) ;
Npts = length(cs.theta) ;

%// first cross section is the the XZ plane
csY0 = zeros(1,Npts) ;  %// will be used as base for rotating cross sections
csX = sin(cs.theta) * cs.radius ;
csZ = cos(cs.theta) * cs.radius ;
```

The rest of the code is the same, you'll obtain your doughnut:
[image: the doughnut]

*I included that anyway because that was my first answer, until I realized from the comment that you wanted a cylinder!*

Comment: This seems to plot a cylinder without an inner wall, while the torus you pictured does seem to have an inner wall. Can you explain?

Comment: @mDroidd. Yes, in the second example I did not detail how to plot the inner wall. It is an extra `patch` object which I created just to facilitate the visualization and explanations. If you look at the first example (with the square cross-section), look for the bit of code which i commented `%% // plot (optional, just for intermediate visualisation); hp0=patch(csX+ring.X(1),csY0+ring.Y(1),csZ,'r','FaceAlpha',0.5) ;`. The same can be done for the circular cross-section.